# HTML script tag paths rules

Tags: html

I was working on some project and here is "index.html" file of my Angular project.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="templateApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> MEAN project template </title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- including App scripts -->

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- App scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="configs/app_setup.js"> 
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
</body>

</html>
```

and my project hierarchy as following:

- client (contains: configs(folder) & index.html )
- bower_components

my curious question here: what are the rules for script tags i expected the above "bower_components" path should not work but it works well. 
and the above path and the following one are working without problems, so how that happened although they are different ??!!

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems by default it looks into the root project directory, and then check for relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

This one would make the directory go up one level from the directory that your `index.html` is located in

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Where as the following one would make the folder `bower_componets` be in the same directory as your `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```